# Get user.id as a string from clerk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, clerk

I need to get the clerk id to check with the backend but clerk uses a hook which doesnt work in this type of function

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {

  const { isLoaded, isSignedIn, user } = useUser();

 

  const userman = user.id;

 

  const posts = await prisma.kalender.findMany({

    where:{accountid: userman}

  })

  await prisma.$disconnect();

  return { props: { posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts))  } }

}
```

This is how i would like it to work. Is there a way to get the user.id as a string?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `user.id` to `string`.

`user.id.toString()` or `String(user.id)`, both will act the same if `user.id` is defined.

Ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 0):

You can use type assertion.

**1. Type assertion on `UseUser`.**

First create a new type (above `export const`):

```
interface UseUserT {
  isLoaded: boolean;
  isSignedIn: boolean;
  user: { id: string };
}
```

Then assign this type to `useUser`:

```
const { isLoaded, isSignedIn, user } = useUser() as UseUserT;
```

**2. Type assertion on `user.id`.**

```
const userman = user.id as string;
```